# Is it possible to skip the particular SQL statement from auto sql tuning advisor job

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration, sql-tuning

I am facing an ORA:7445 issue with auto sql tuning advisor. Auto sql tuning advisor keeps failing with

> ORA:7445

while it's tries to tune a particular SQL.

Is there any way to skip this sql statement from auto sql tuning advisor job?

Comment: It is a oracle11gR2 database.

Comment: you'd be better served in filing an SR with MOS to get the 7445 addressed/fixed.

Comment: Did you check alert log about more information? may be oracle wrote more info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to avoid the Automatic SQL Tuning Advisor may be to convert the query into a form that is not supported by the program.

According to [the "Automatic SQL Tuning" chapter of the "Database Performance Tuning Guide"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e16638/sql_tune.htm):

> The database ignores recursive SQL and statements that have been tuned
>   recently (in the last month), parallel queries, DML, DDL, and SQL
>   statements with performance problems caused by concurrency issues.

If the query `select * from dba_objects` was causing problems, try re-writing it like this:

```
select * from dba_objects
union all
--This query block only exists to avoid the Automatic SQL Tuning Advisor.
select /*+ parallel(dba_objects 2) */ * from dba_objects 
where 1=0;
```

It is now a "parallel query" although it will not truly run in parallel because of the `1=0`.  I haven't tested this, and I imagine it will be difficult for you to test, because you'll need to flush the existing AWR data to prevent the errors.

This is one of the reasons why I usually disable the Automatic SQL Tuning Advisor.  I like the idea of it, but in practice I've literally never seen the tuning advisor provide useful information.  All it has ever done for me is generate alerts.

---

In *theory*,the package [DBMS_AUTO_SQLTUNE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_autosta.htm#ARPLS73155) contains the parameters `BASIC_FILTER`, `OBJECT_FILTER`, and `PLAN_FILTER`.  I assume one of those could be useful but I don't think they are implemented yet.  I can't find any references to them on Google or My Oracle Support.  And when I entered random text for the values there were no errors.

---

Ideally we would look up every ORA-00600 and ORA-07445 error, create an SR, and fix the underlying problem.  But who has time for that?   when you encounter a database "bug", the best solution is usually to avoid it as quickly as possible.